# How to show a window within another window in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, window

I have a MDIarea in my window and the code I have typed to show me a new window in the MDIarea is here(I have two Qwidget windows which I want to show within the mainwindow):

```
 InnerCompanySignupWindow A(sys);
InnerPersonSignUpWindow B(sys);
if(arg1 == "Company"){
  // ui->InTheWindow->hide();
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(&A);
    ui->mdiArea->activateNextSubWindow();
   // ui->mdiArea->removeSubWindow(&B);
//        hide();
}
if(arg1 == "Person"){
   // ui->InTheWindow->hide();
    ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(&B);
    ui->mdiArea->activateNextSubWindow();
    //ui->mdiArea->removeSubWindow(&A);
    //        hide();
}
```

what should I do? is using MDIarea is the right thing?

Comment: Its based on your personal preference but most of the projects now a days use tab widget as central widget instead of using MDI area. But for Mdi application use can use the  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the mdi child widget for specific arguments and set that widget as active sub window.

```
QMdiSubWindow *existing = findMdiChild(arg); // your custom function to find subwindow
if (existing) {
    mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(existing);
    return;
}
```

For more infromation you can follow this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html).